# Error while plotting solution of 6th order equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerical-value

Mathematica isn't my strong suit, but I am trying to solve a mathematical equation with it. The equation is

[image]

The code I used to solve is as follows :-

```
AR = 13;
Msys = 500853.6*10^(-18);
bleg = 1.5*10^(-6);
b = 4.5*10^(-6);
L = AR*b  (*Length of the Cantilever*)
emr1 = 0.29020; (*Effective Mass Ratio for Mode 1*)
emr2 = 0.27914; (*Effective Mass Ratio for Mode 2*)
meff1 = emr1*Msys
meff2 = emr2*Msys
α1 =0.044; (*Nonlinear Coefficient for Mode 1*)
G = 1*10^(-9); (*in N*)
Q = 1000;
f1 = 159964.55; (*in Hz*)
f2 = 1.142549412*10^6; (*in Hz*)
keff1 = meff1*(2*π*f1)^2
keff2 = meff2*(2*π*f2)^2
ω1m = 2*π*f1
ω2m = 2*π*f2
EQN1n = (G/(2*keff1))^2/(((((f*ω1m - ω1m)/ω1m) - 3*α1*(x^2)/(8*L^2))^2 + (1/(2*Q))^2)) == x^2
SOL1 = Solve[EQN1n,x];
X12 = x*10^6/.SOL1〚2〛;
X14 = x*10^6/.SOL1〚4〛;
X16 = x*10^6/.SOL1〚6〛;
SOL1//Length
Plot[{X12//Abs,X14//Abs,X16//Abs},{f,0.995,1.005},PlotLegends->"Expressions",PlotRange->All,PlotPoints->100,Frame->True]
```

The output I get is

[image]

Whereas I should be getting something like

[image]

Is there a reason my output is, for lack of better word, noisy? Is it possibly due to really small numbers as input?

Comment: Solutions are in pairs which are solutions of the cubic in x^2.  You can look at properties of the cubic (discriminant etc.) to gain some insight into the behaviours of the roots.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation can be solved exactly: set the parameters *after* solving:

```
eq = 
  (G/(2*keff1))^2 / 
    (((((f*ω1m - ω1m)/ω1m) - 3*α1*(x^2)/(8*L^2))^2 + (1/(2*Q))^2)) - x^2 == 0

 module[f_] = 10^6*Abs@x /. Solve[eq, x];

 (* define parameters *)

 Plot[Evaluate[module[f]], {f, 0.995, 1.002}]
```

[image]

It's not the plot your looking for but that's not my fault :)

Comment: Yeah, I am playing around with some parameters so things might not look exact. Is it possible to plot only some of the roots from this? The equation has 6 roots, I only need the 2nd, 4th and 6th

Comment: @Saransh Try `Plot[Evaluate[module[f][[{2, 4, 6}]]], {f, 0.995, 1.002}, 
 PlotPoints -> 200]`

Answer (score 1):

If you rationalize (make them exact numbers) all your variables you get the following plot:
[image]

Comment: In addition to using exact constants, `FullSimplify` `SOL1`and specify `WorkingPrecision -> 20` in the plot.